# How to determine active F5 in device group via iControl REST API

Tags: api, rest, f5

I am looking for a way to determine which device in a device group (cluster) of F5 load balancers (LTMs) is "active" via the F5 iControl REST API. I have perused the entirety of the /sys endpoint where I would expect such information to be contained to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, documenting it here in case anyone else is curious.

In the 11.5.3 version of the REST API the state of a given F5 in a device group can be found in the /cm/device endpoint in the 'failoverState' property which will be either "active" or "standby" in typical operation.